# How to write select statement with a condition of case-insensitive from a select query output

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

I'm getting data like this

- Doha
- doha
- Dubai
- Abu Dhabi
- Abu dhabi

from the query `select distinct(trim(name)) as loc from locations order by trim(name)`

Now I want to remove duplicates using lower() or upper() and select the first record .
If I use lower function like below,

```
select distinct(lower(A.loc)) from( select distinct(trim(name)) as loc from locations order by trim(name) ) as A order by lower(A.loc);
```

it gives result converted to lower as below.

- doha
- dubai
- abu dhabi

  But I want original result as previously mentioned.
- Doha
- Dubai
- Abu Dhabi

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. `distinct a` is the same as `distinct (a)` and consequently, `distinct a,b,c` is the same as `distinct (a),b,c` or `distinct a,b,(c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=78082dc8b708c99660d042b4fb6855cc)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (lower(city))
    city
FROM
    cities
```

`DISTINCT ON` takes an arbitrary column and gives out the first one of duplicates. In this case a column is created internally with all lower case. Then the first record is taken, but only the original column.

---

**NOTE** You have no special order. It will be taken a random order (which is for example how data is stored internally). To achieve the upper case value you have to write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (lower(city))
    city
FROM
    cities
ORDER BY lower(city), city DESC
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c4c437663f2d308073ce08d77f3d906b)

The `ORDER BY lower(city)` is necessary because the `DISTINCT ON` needs the given columns to be the first ordered. After that you can order by any other column. `ORDER BY column DESC` moves the upper cases top.